# Hirschberg's algorithm for long strings of bits

Tags: strings, error-correcting-codes

Let $a$ be a large string of bits that is transmitted over a channel that introduces errors (insertions, deletions or substitutions) where the probability of an error happening is $p=0.01$ for each bit. Suppose also that each type of error has a probability of $1/3$ being chosen each time that an error is introduced to $a$. Let $b$ be the resulting string after transmission.

My question is: Given $a$ and an index $i$ in $a$, is there an efficient way to find the closest corresponding index $j$ in $b$? (Suppose that for a given $a$ we are going to request a large number indices $i$, so we must find an efficient way of determining $j$).

I have tried tackling this problem using the *Levenshtein distance* and trying to find the the optimal sequence alignment using *Hirschberg's algorithm* which takes $\mathcal{O}(nm)$ where $|a|=n$ and $|b|=m$. Then using this sequence alignment it doesn't matter how many requests you make, you can always find $j$ in $\mathcal{O}(1)$, i.e., each request takes $\mathcal{O}(1)$, but the algorithm still takes $\mathcal{O}(nm)$.

I think this approach might work, however, is there a more efficient way to do this given that $a$ and $b$ are just strings of $1$'s and $0$'s and that the probability of an error happening is relatively low?

Comment: Answering your second question, *forward error correction* is, *by definition*, the solution to this problem. There is no "simpler" or "more naive" way. Alternatives to forward error correction are more general communication protocols, in which the receiver communicates with the sender as well.

Comment: In any case, the usual rule is one question per post. If you have several different questions, you can ask them separately.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, sorry, when I said "but it might be a simpler more naive way of doing this", I meant that it might be a simpler way than adding redundancy or using CRC.

Comment: I can also split the question in two different posts if you think is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, it would indeed be more appropriate.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, done!